# Incrementar dentro do subscribe

Tags: typescript, angular-6

Tenho este método que recebe a lista **data**, o que funciona, após uma consulta no banco de dados.

```
private preencherPlanosSaudes() {
    this.planoSaudeService.buscarTodos().subscribe(
      (data : any[]) => {
        let ps   = new EnumModel();
        ps.key   = data[0].id;
        ps.texto = data[0].nome;
        this.planosSaudes.push(ps);
      }
    );
  }
```

Mas dentro do **subscribe**, preciso de um contador para ficar assim:

```
private preencherPlanosSaudes() {
    let contador = 0;
    this.planoSaudeService.buscarTodos().subscribe(
      (data : any[]) => {
        let ps   = new EnumModel();
        ps.key   = data[contador].id;
        ps.texto = data[0contador].nome;
        this.planosSaudes.push(ps);
       contador ++;
      }
    );
  }
```

Mas não funciona.O que estou fazendo de errado ?

Comment: como vc sabe que não funciona?

Answer (score 0):

Funcionou assim:

> ```
> private preencherPlanosSaudes() {
>     this.planoSaudeService.buscarTodos().subscribe(
>       (data : any[]) => {
>         data.forEach(
>           d => {
>             let ps   = new EnumModel();
>             ps.key   = d.id;
>             ps.texto = d.nome;
>             this.planosSaudes.push(ps);
>           }
>         );
>       }
>     );
> ```